# Combine Rows with Similar Values in a Column VBA

Tags: excel, vba

There is a code I found on Stack Overflow and it combines rows that have the same values in column A but what I cant do is modify the code for it to combine rows with similar values in column A.

For Example:

[image]
the merged or combined row should have after the code is ran but what it does it looks each value in column A as a unique value:

Results Should be: 101  102  12

Please can someone assist me in modifying or share a code that will cobine rows that have samilar values in Column A. Thank you in advance.

```
   Sub CombineRows()

    Dim Rng As Range, _
                    Dn As Range _
                    , N As Long _
                    , nRng As Range

    On Error Resume Next

    Set Rng = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A" & Rows.count).End(xlUp))
    With CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
    .CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    For Each Dn In Rng
        If Not .Exists(Dn.Value) Then
            .Add Dn.Value, Dn
        Else
            If nRng Is Nothing Then Set nRng = _
            Dn Else Set nRng = Union(nRng, Dn)
            .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 2) = .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 2) + 
             Dn.Offset(, 2)
            .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 3) = .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 3) + 
             Dn.Offset(, 3)
            .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 4) = .Item(Dn.Value).Offset(, 4) + 
             Dn.Offset(, 4)


        End If
    Next
    If Not nRng Is Nothing Then nRng.EntireRow.Delete
    End With


    End Sub
```

Answer from @DecimalTurn. I adjusted the string variables;  Shortstring & Longsting to take out the any commas from the string.

```
Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    For Each c1 In Rng

        Dim ShortString  As String
        ShortString = Replace(c1.Value2, ",", "")

        For Each c2 In Rng

            If c2.row > c1.row Then 'Because we sorted the rows, we only need to look at the row if it's a row below c1.

                Dim LongString  As String
                LongString = Replace(c2.Value2, ",", "")

                If InStr(LongString, ShortString) > 0 Then

                    'Add Combine similar lines
                    c1.Offset(, 2).Value2 = c1.Offset(, 2).Value2 + c2.Offset(, 2).Value2
                    c1.Offset(, 3).Value2 = c1.Offset(, 3).Value2 + c2.Offset(, 3).Value2
                    c1.Offset(, 4).Value2 = c1.Offset(, 4).Value2 + c2.Offset(, 4).Value2

                    'Delete current line since it has a similar value as the shorter one.
                    c2.EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            End If

        Next c2
    Next c1
```

Comment: How are the values similar to each other? What sort of pattern of similarity are we dealing with? Without more detail, it's hard to propose a solution.

Comment: They are simiar beacuse they both have "joro1" so part of the text exists in xlValues.  I know that if you used the Find method and you can use the parameter LookAt xlPart it does the following; Match against any part of the search text.(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xllookat). Did I provide enough detail?

Comment: Can you edit your question to add the source of the code you pasted?

Comment: Can you specify where you want to write the combined line after combining the similar rows? At the bottom?

Comment: Cant remember where I got the code but I do not take any credit. It has been over a year I havent revised the macro.

Comment: I would prefer to keep the combine line and delete the other similar rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And easy way to see if two [strings](http://codevba.com/learn/strings.htm#.XWDDl-hKiUk) are "similar" is to test if one string is contained in the other. To do that you could use the function `InStr`.

Here is an example of how to use it:

```
Sub TestInstr()

    Dim txt1 As String, txt2 As String
    txt1 = ActiveSheet.Range("A1")
    txt2 = ActiveSheet.Range("A2")

    Dim Substring As String, FullString As String

    If Len(txt1) <= Len(txt2) Then

        Substring = txt1
        FullString = txt2

    Else

        Substring = txt2
        FullString = txt1

    End If


    If InStr(FullString, Substring) > 0 Then

        'This code runs when the substring is included somewhere inside the full string

    Else

        'This code runs when the substring is not included anywhere inside the full string

    End If

End Sub
```

In order to implement this for more than 2 lines, we can adapt par of the code you submitted and make it the **first step** of our code. This step makes sure that we already combined lines that have exactly the same value in column A. For **step 2**, we need to sort by the length of the values in column A in order so we can easily loop over them in the next step. In **step 3**, we loop over the range (in a double loop) and check if the shorter column A values (c1) appear in any cells below them (c2). If yes, then we combine those 2 rows.

Here's how it would look like:

```
Sub CombineRows()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ActiveSheet

    Dim Rng As Range
    Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp))

    Dim RangeValues As Object
    Set RangeValues = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    RangeValues.CompareMode = vbTextCompare

    '1) Store unique values in dictionary and combine identical rows
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In Rng

        If Not RangeValues.Exists(c.Value) Then

            RangeValues.Add c.Value2, c

        Else

            'Add Combine identical lines
            RangeValues.Item(c.Value).Offset(, 1).Value2 = RangeValues.Item(c.Value).Offset(, 1).Value2 + c.Offset(, 1).Value2
            RangeValues.Item(c.Value).Offset(, 2).Value2 = RangeValues.Item(c.Value).Offset(, 2).Value2 + c.Offset(, 2).Value2
            RangeValues.Item(c.Value).Offset(, 3).Value2 = RangeValues.Item(c.Value).Offset(, 3).Value2 + c.Offset(, 3).Value2

            'Delete current line since it has the same value as another existing one.
            c.EntireRow.Delete

        End If

    Next

    '2) Sort the range by shortest string length
    ws.Columns("A:A").Insert Shift:=xlToRight

    For Each c In Rng
        c.Offset(0, -1).Value2 = Len(c.Value2)
    Next c

    Dim TableRange As Range
    Const NbOfColumns As Long = 5
    Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Reset
    Set TableRange = Rng.Resize(Rng.Rows.Count, NbOfColumns + 1)

    ws.Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ws.Sort.SortFields.Add2 Key:=TableRange.Columns(1) _
        , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ws.Sort
        .SetRange TableRange
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

    ws.Columns("A:A").Delete Shift:=xlToLeft

    Set Rng = ws.Range(ws.Range("A1"), ws.Range("A" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)) 'Reset

    '3) Combine similar rows (ie. rows where the shortest value is included in the longest)
    Dim c1 As Range, c2 As Range
    For Each c1 In Rng

        Dim ShortString  As String
        ShortString = c1.Value2

        For Each c2 In Rng

            If c2.Row > c1.Row Then 'Because we sorted the rows, we only need to look at the row if it's under c1.

                Dim LongString  As String
                LongString = c2.Value2

                If InStr(LongString, ShortString) > 0 Then

                    'Add Combine similar lines
                    c1.Offset(, 1).Value2 = c1.Offset(, 1).Value2 + c2.Offset(, 1).Value2
                    c1.Offset(, 2).Value2 = c1.Offset(, 2).Value2 + c2.Offset(, 2).Value2
                    c1.Offset(, 3).Value2 = c1.Offset(, 3).Value2 + c2.Offset(, 3).Value2

                    'Delete current line since it has a similar value as the shorter one.
                    c2.EntireRow.Delete
                End If

            End If

        Next c2
    Next c1

End Sub
```

To test it, I generated the data using the macro below and got the desired result:

[image]

```
Sub FillData()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Add(After:=ActiveSheet)

With ws

    Range("A1").Value2 = "joro1. Inc"
    Range("A2").Value2 = "joro1"

    Range("B1").Value2 = "100"
    Range("B2").Value2 = "1"

    Range("C1").Value2 = "100"
    Range("C2").Value2 = "2"

    Range("D1").Value2 = "10"
    Range("D2").Value2 = "2"

End With

End Sub
```

Comment: How would you look thorugh column A to see if dynamic values are similar. For example; in row 4 of Column A the Value is "Joro." , Row 5: " Can, Inc." Row: 6: "Joro,. Com" , Row 7: "Can,.". Because my data may have x Rows and different values that are similar. TIA

Comment: @jo ro  I added some comments under your question asking for certain precisions that will help me adapt the code you gave to use what I suggested. Please make those and I will edit my answer accordingly.

Comment: @ DecimalTurn I replied to your comments. Please let me know if you need additional information. TIA

Comment: @joro - It would probably be better if you had a predefined list of strings you want to look for like "Joro", "Can", etc. You could then combine all rows that include those substring. What do you think?

Comment: I had thought about that and would have to create a mapping sheet or reference sheet then the user would have to periodically update the reference sheet with new values and it could be x new values. I'm trying to avoid that route because it requires the user to update x Values . Could there be another way?

Comment: @joro - Without this information, the code will need to implement an algorithm to decide what is going to be the strings to use for comparison. I'm thinking of a loop that would start with the shortest text value and end with the longest text value. At each value it would combine together all the line that include this value. Would that work for you?

Comment: @jo ro - I made what I expect to be the final edit to my question. As a reminder, if this (or any future answer) solves your question, please consider accepting it by [clicking the check mark beside it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/372533).. This is not an obligation, but it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself.

Comment: thank you for your answer and for being very detailed . I tried running the code with the example below (picture) but the only thing the code did was Step 2.

Comment: @joro I can't see the picture. If you want to include a picture in your comment, you can upload the picture to imgur and put a link to it in your comment.

Comment: @joro Oh, I misread your comment and thought you meant the picture was the outcome after running the code. This is what you started with. So you are saying that the only thing the code did was to sort the 2 lines so that the second line is now the first one?

Comment: @joro in the sheet you tried the code is there more data after row 2?

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses. Correct the joro1 row is at the top. But the picture doesnt show the extra space after joro1 .

Comment: No, the only data I have is the one in the picture.

Comment: Also, I tested it with an additional row that has joro1., Inc in A3 and the other data was inputed radomly and didnt recognize it neither for Step 3.

Comment: @joro  I'm sorry but the code works perfectly on my end and I don't have enough info to know what doesn't work for you. I can suggest you to [debug the code](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html)  using some breakpoints to make sure that the code execute properly, but I can't do more at this point unless you share the workbook you are working in.

Comment: let me work the phony workbook. I'm unble to share the data. The problem is with the periods and commas.

Comment: @joro I just realized there is a problem with the offset that you had in the code you provided and the image you provided. I changed my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Also, I've added a section at the end so you can replicate the result that I get. Just run `FillData` and then `CombineRows' should give you the desired result.

Comment: thank you for all your prompt responses. Offline due to other matters. Thank you for catching the offset error for me.

Comment: I tried your FillData Macro and I edited your response with a new FillData Macro. I tried the CombineRows Macro but it didnt work for the data the FillData Macro filled in for me. Could you please check it for me. TIA

Comment: @joro It would make more sense to add it to your question instead.

Comment: The macro won't make any changes in the example you gave since "joro1, LLC" does not containt a "joro1 LLC". You could have the macro remove the punctuation mark before comparing if you want those 2 to be considered similar.

Comment: I will be more descriptive next time . Thank you

Comment: I don’t know how to implement that into the code but I will do some research. Or would you be able to assist me with that?

Comment: I'm certain that figured out how to take out the comma from the strings. Thank you for all your help and time.

Comment: I posted your answer with my adjustments. The adjustments are posted in my question.

Comment: @joro Wonderful, I'm happy you were able to solve your issue. Cheers!